# How to get "People Also Like" using FQL or Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

As mentioned above, I want to get name and page_URL(website) on `People Also Like` list using FQL OR Facebook Graph API.

I was making some Query for FQL such as:

```
select page_id, name, username, page_url, website from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid= "")
```

But it gives `Liked by this page` not for `People Also like`
Please give me your kind advices for getting `People Also Like` lists.